# Why is my Upsolver Kafka data source is stuck and/or not pulling any data

Tags: sqlake, upsolver

Kafta topic has messages but Upsolver data source is stuck or not pulling any new messages. We have about 15 such data sources and some are working fine but some seem stuck. What is happening?

Answer (score 0):

When Kafka data source is created there is a configuration "Read From Start". When true (checked), the Kafka DS will only pull data if there were any messages in the topic at the time of Data source creation. If topic was empty, this Data source will get stuck and stalled. In such a case, data source should be created with this Read from start property unchecked. And then the data source will start pulling messages from the point of its creation.

Alternatively, you could play a sample dummy message per your schema in the topic before you create the data source with Read from Start = True if you don't or can't wait for data to arrive before creating.